# I created a public account but all options are not available to me

Tags: viber

Example: communicating with subscribers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCVKk.jpg)

what to do?

checked on all versions Viber and on all types of mobile phones but compared to the result there is no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 : 1 communication with subscribers is reserved for chatbots or some CRM solutions that would allow agent chat.

You should read [this part of documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/general/get-started/) for a start.